# Текст на границе

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите. пожалуйста, как сделать текст на границе?  как указано на скрине? помнится я находил тег. но не помню как называется (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <fieldset>
   <legend>Для кого лучше всего подходит</legend>
   <p>телемаркетинг</p>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей используется метка <[fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)>:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>О нас</legend>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>О Вас</legend>
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```